# For Christmas Lights, is it safe to run extension cord under garage door?

Tags: lighting, garage, extension-cord

For Christmas Lights over the garage, the nearest outlet is inside my garage. Is it safe to run an extension cord under the garage door to the outlet? Is there anything I should bear in mind while doing so (like specific types of outdoor cords)?

The garage type is one that has wheels on the side, attached to a metal track. It has a rubber seal at the bottom, which looks kinda like [this](http://www.elite-xpressions.com/bottomseal_double_t_image.jpg).

Comment: Personally I do it every year, but it really depends on your door.  In my case the cord depresses a rubber weatherstrip and the cord lays flat.  Looking at the cord, It would be hard to tell at the end of the christmas season that it had a garage door opening and closing on it.  That said I've seen cases where I'd never do this.... And that's likely the answer your going to get here.  Make sure it's plugged into a GFCI receptacle.

Comment: I can run a cable at the side but not under the door without unacceptable pressure and scuffing. The side seals are soft rubber flaps. But you have to hold the cable up as you shut the door. I doubt you'll get a definitive answer but you haven't told us anything about the door: up-and-over? Roller shutter? Swing doors? Weather sealed?

Comment: @ChrisH - I've updated the question with those details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes to the last: you certainly need outdoor-rated extension cords for anything exiting the house.

Now, as to how to run the cord:  the comments cover your planned implementation.  I would strongly recommend, however that you or your friendly electrician run wire (properly inside conduit) from the existing internal outlet to a new external outlet box.  The hardware cost is trivial, and the work involved in attaching to the existing wiring, drilling a small hole in the wall next to the garage doors (or whatever is the preferred location) is easy.  Plus you now have an outdoor outlet for general use.